# Android DataBinding - Why Data Binding not support @mipmap images

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

Using DataBinding, I trying to access icon from mipmap folder, after write a code it not compile model class and it show error in log - "**token recognition error**". Look at the below screenshot even it not allowed @mipmap. If anyone know the reason Please let me know

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_page1"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/splash_slider_circle"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/splash_slider_circle"
            android:src="@{slider.img1 ? @mipmap/ic_circle_filled : @mipmap/ic_circle_outline}" />
```

[image]

Comment: No , If i try same code drawable folder it works

Comment: may I know what's mistake in  that condition

Comment: what are you asking if it's true in your condition?

Comment: @Nikos I didn't get you

Comment: Maybe try to write a custom binding for this. Then you can also hide the logic within the binding and name it accordingly, so you know what happens.

app:sliderBinding='@{slider.img1}'

Comment: the expression x?y:z means if x is true do y else do z. I was trying to understand what slider.img1 means

Comment: yeah what is slider.img1?

Comment: @Vadivel did you find any reason behind it? I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

The exact reason for the described behaviour is unknown to me. But if it's inconvenient to move all your icons from mipmap to drawable folders, it's possible to import your generated R class in the layout and refer mipmaps in conditions starting with `R.mipmap` and using `app:imageResource` attribute:

```
<data>
  <import type="your.package.R" />
  ...
</data>
<ImageView
   ...
   app:imageResource="@{someConditionVariable ? R.mipmap.ic_for_true_condition : R.mipmap.ic_for_false_condition}"
   ... />
```